# Unable to perform "sudo npm install --save firebase-admin"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

i'm unable to perform `sudo npm install --save firebase-admin` in terminal. The error I'm getting is:

```
npm WARN package.json crypto@0.0.3 crypto is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json express-resource@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! Error: Invalid Package: expected types/jsonwebtoken but found @types/jsonwebtoken

npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local-tarball.js:161:14
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "firebase-admin"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Henry/work_space/ServerMain
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I don't see `types/jsonwebtoken` or anything in my `package.json` file. 
I'm suspecting this could be because my node and firebase is out of date?
my node is 1.4.28 and my firebase is 2.4.2. Let me know if you guys have any ideas!

Comment: I do not know why this is not working, but your node version seems really old : the latest version of node is `7.2.0` (https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Your node version is even older than that: node -v v0.10.38

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're suspecting that your Node is out of date then have you tried to install it with a newer version of Node? - i.e. [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

First of all your Node is not v1.4.28 but v0.10.38 - read your own question, it's right there.

Node 0.10 was released on March 2013 and stopped being maintained on October 2016. Its current status is "End-of-Life" so don't expect it to work for any new modules, unless those modules explicitly state that they work with that version of Node (which this one doesn't) and even then don't expect it to work well. See the [Node LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS):

[image]

Node 0.10 uses a very old version of V8 (3.14.5.x) so you can't even use modern JavaScript. By contrast Node 7.2.0 uses V8 version 5.4.500.43. See [V8 Changelog](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/ChangeLog) to know was changed in the meantime.

Even [io.js was forked](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/nodejs-iojs-why-the-fork/) from Node 0.12 because of not incorporating V8 releases fast enough in 0.12 and you're using a version that's even older than that.

There is no reason to use Node 0.10 when new versions are available for free.

If you don't know how to install a newer version of Node then see [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) or [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).